# Iterating through CSV file - command viewed as one item

Tags: expansion, loops, xstring, csv

I'm trying to iterate through a CSV file, but am running into trouble. The file is multiple lines and I want to go through the CSV items one-by-item. When using the etoolbox docsvlist, it inerprets the line break as a space. So I try to fix this (and successfully do) by replacing a space character with a comma. The only issue now is that the csv iterator interprets that command as a single item. I believe this problem has to do with expansion, and I've tried many edef / expandafter solutons etc. to no avail.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}
    \CatchFileDef{\CSVdata}{FILE.csv}{}% Formatted CSV data
    \newcommand{\CSVdataNoSpaces}{\StrSubstitute[0]{\CSVdata}{ }{,}}    
    \renewcommand{\do}[1]{#1\\}% new line in between items
    \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\CSVdataNoSpaces} % considers the command one csv item
    \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\CSVdata} % iterates thru, but spaces are problem
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `\CSVdataNoSpaces` to expand to the token-sequence `\StrSubstitute[0]{\CSVdata}{ }{,}`.

The `\expandafter`-chain in `\expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\CSVdataNoSpaces}` delivers this token-sequence, thus you get something like `\docsvlist{\StrSubstitute[0]{\CSVdata}{ }{,}}`.

Thus the argument of `\docsvlist` is the token-sequence `\StrSubstitute[0]{\CSVdata}{ }{,}`.

The token-sequence `\StrSubstitute[0]{\CSVdata}{ }{,}` does not contain any comma not nested in curly braces. Thus that entire token-sequence is considered the only element of the csv-list/of the comma-separated-values-list.

But you are in luck:

`\StrSubstitute` takes an optional argument denoting a control-sequence-token which is to be (re-)defined to be a macro which delivers as top-level-expansion the tokens that form the result of `\StrSubstitute`.
Thus you can do `\StrSubstitute[0]{\CSVdata}{ }{,}[\CSVdataNoSpaces]`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}
    \CatchFileDef{\CSVdata}{FILE.csv}{}% Formatted CSV data
    % \expandarg     % -> xstring-macros "hit" the 1st-token of arguments with \expandafter once before processing them further. 
    % \fullexpandarg % -> xstring-macros apply `\edef` to the arguments before processing them further.
    % \noexpandarg   % -> xstring-macros process arguments as is, without applying whatsoever expansion to them before processing them.
                     % \fullexpandarg is the default.
                     % See the xstring-manual for more information.
                     % If you wish \StrSubstitute to work on the result
                     % of expanding \CSVdata, you need \expandarg (->
                     % \StrSubstitute works on \CSVdata's toplevel-
                     % expansion) or \fullexpandarg (-> \StrSubstitute
                     % works on \CSVdata's full expansion/\edef-expansion) .
    \StrSubstitute[0]{\CSVdata}{ }{,}[\CSVdataNoSpaces]%
    \show\CSVdata
    \show\CSVdataNoSpaces
    \renewcommand{\do}[1]{#1\\}% new line in between items
    \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\CSVdataNoSpaces}% iterates thru, spaces are turned into commas which might be a problem with spaces placed into the file on purpose
    \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\CSVdata} % iterates thru, but spaces are problem
\end{document}
```

**I recommend a different approach:**

Instead of doing this `\StrSubstitute`-game, you can "tell" `\CatchFileDef` to append a comma instead of a space with every line-end—this might be more save because this way you won't get spaces replaced which were placed into the .csv-file on purpose:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\begin{document}
    \CatchFileDef{\CSVdata}{FILE.csv}{\endlinechar=`\,}% Formatted CSV data
    \show\CSVdata
    \renewcommand{\do}[1]{#1\\}% new line in between items
    \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\CSVdata}% iterates thru.
\end{document}
```

Depending on what data the .csv-file contains you might be interested in Dr. Nicola Talbot's [datatool](https://ctan.org/pkg/datatool)-package.